# Small error when using .htaccess for clean urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess to manage clean URL's but for some reason I get a 404 Not Found Apache error in some cases.

If a user goes to `http://domain.com/profile/` everything is fine.

If a user goes to `http://domain.com/profile` they will get the error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&cmd=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# /profile/cmd
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&cmd=$2 [L]

# /profile
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the url with the url which has trailing slash using 301 redirect

Try the following along with your rewrite condition. This will redirect any url request to url with trailing slash. ex. http://domain.com/profile will be redirected to http://domain.com/profile/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule you wrote requires one slash '/'.
Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?$ /index.php?page=$1&cmd=$3 [L]
```